# TypeError, using a number to calculate in print

Tags: python, typeerror

How can I make this line work?
print('Average state population:', totalPop/50)

it won't let me because the 50 is an int.

```
def main ():
file = open ('StateCensus2010.txt', 'r')
name = file.readline()
abb = file.readline()
pop = file.readline()
minPop = pop
minName = name
maxPop = pop
maxName = name
totalPop = pop
totalPop += pop   
for state in range (49):
    name = file.readline()
    abb = file.readline()
    pop = file.readline()
    if pop < minPop:
        minPop = pop
        minName = name
    if pop > maxPop:
        maxPop = pop
        minName = name
print(' State with MAX population:',maxName, maxPop)
print('State with MIN population:', minName, minPop)
print('Average state population:', totalPop/50)
```

Comment: Can you show your full code? i.e. what is totalPop?

Comment: What exactly is the error? Post the full traceback.

Comment: That works fine when `totalPop` is an integer. Please post the actual error message including the full traceback.

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int' is the traceback. just included the full code

Comment: `pop` is a string, so `totalPop` is also a string.

Comment: How should I set it up to where the totalPop can be divisible by a number?

Answer (score 0):

You should use either `print('Average state population: {}'.format(totalPop/50))` or `print('Average state population:', str(totalPop/50))`, but preferably the first. This uses [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) which automatically converts types to strings.

Comment: still get the trace back error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'" ):

Comment: That would be because `totalPop` is a string. Convert it to an int (perhaps using `int`) before performing the division.

Comment: @DW42 it needs to be converted far earlier than that, as do all the strings representing numbers.

Comment: yeah, I just don't know where to convert it or if there's another way to do it.

Comment: You could do something like `print('Average state population: {}'.format(int(totalPop)/50))`.

Comment: No good : ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4802982\n4802982\n'   ):

Comment: I think you need to look at how you're getting the populations...